# Vanilla ReactJS include sub component in JSX file

Tags: reactjs

Good morning. I'm attempting to use vanilla React (without the use of NodeJS) to add in some components to our existing site.

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.2.1/react.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.2.1/react-dom.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-core/5.8.34/browser.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/babel" src="./js/React/src/Contact_Form.jsx"></script>
```

Working with NodeJS previously I was using eg. `var Button = require("./button");` within my .jsx file to include additional sub components.

Is there a way with vanilla React to accomplish this?

For example:

index.html -> form.jsx -> (input.jsx, select.jsx, button.jsx)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Components are just objects / functions so you can put them in some shared namespace.

```
window.ReactComponents = window.ReactComponents || {}
window.ReactComponents.Button = props => <button />
```

Then in some other file:

```
var Button = window.ReactComponents 
  ? window.ReactComponents.Button
  : <span />

var CoolButton = props => <Button style={{ color: 'blue' }} />
```